# Supporting Shift+Enter to input multiple lines with GNU Readline

Tags: c, readline

I'm using GNU Readline, mostly for its history features, to make a REPL for a programming language, but I need the ability to enter multiple lines. I'd like to support pressing Shift+Enter to enter a newline without submitting. I'd like to leave Enter (without Shift) bound to submit still.

I wasn't able to find anyone else doing this online with GNU Readline. I'm guessing I need to do something with one of the `rl_bind_` functions [here](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#Binding-Keys), but I'm not sure where to start.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161495/is-there-a-nice-way-of-handling-multi-line-input-with-gnu-readline) but I'm not sure why he's printf-ing and it doesn't say how to specify the Shift key being depressed.

Comment: I think this is going to be hard, because most terminals, be they actual hardware devices (a rare sight nowadays!) or software terminal-in-a-window emulators, simply don’t differentiate between enter and shift-enter.

Comment: @TurePålsson, yeah, after more research, it looks like readline isn't actually reading keys, it's reading *emitted characters from stdin*, and since shift doesn't emit characters, this can't be done using  normal readline functions. I found operating-system specific ways to do this for a few platforms, but I'm not sure I'm ready to take on a cross-platform support nightmare for this feature.